# How to list all zip files in a directory?

Tags: bash, scripting

Ubuntu 16.04

I tried this:

```
for file in $source/*.zip
do
        echo $file
done
```

and it works if the directory contains `zip` files. It prints out all them. But if it does not, it just print the `$source/*.zip`. I mean if `source=/home/usrname/dir` which does not contain any `zip`s then it prints

```
/home/usrname/dir/*.zip
```

Is there a way to make it print nothing in that case?

Comment: @don_crissti yours is more appropriate!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use:

```
find "$source" -name "*.zip"
```

And if needed pipe it to [xargs](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/xargs.1.html) 
or use:

```
shopt -s dotglob
for file in "${source}"/*.zip
do
   if [ -f "${file}" ]; then
      printf '%s\n' "$file"
   fi
done
```

To print only the `zip` files that are regular files or symlinks to regular files.

Answer (score 1):

### `bash`

```
shopt -s nullglob dotglob
files=("$dir"/*.zip)
((${#files[@])) && printf '%s\n' "${files[@]}"
shopt -u nullglob dotglob # if needed
```

### `zsh`

```
files=($dir/*.zip(ND))
(($#files)) && printf '%s\n' $files
```

### `fish`

```
set files $dir/.*.zip $dir/*.zip
if count $files > /dev/null
  printf '%s\n' $files
end
```

(beware it would omit a file called `.zip` though (contrary to the other solutions given here)).

### `ksh93`

```
FIGNORE='@(.|..)'
files=(~(N)"$dir"/*.zip)
((${#files[@])) && printf '%s\n' "${files[@]}"
unset FIGNORE # if needed
```

### `yash`

```
set -o dot-glob -o null-glop
files=("$dir"/*.zip)
[ "${files[#]}" -gt 0 ] && printf '%s\n' "$files"
set +o got-glob +o null-glob # if needed
```

### POSIXly

```
export LC_ALL=C
set -- "$dir"/[*].zip "$dir"/*.zip
case ${1##*/}${2##*/} in
  '[*].zip*.zip') shift 2
esac
set -- "$dir"/.[*].zip "$dir"/.*.zip "$@"
case ${1##*/}${2##*/} in
  '.[*].zip.*.zip') shift 2
esac
[ "$#" -gt 0 ] && printf '%s\n' "$@"
```